# How to execute multiple dependent updateSelectInput() sequentially on calling onRestored()

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to use bookmarking in a shiny app but am having trouble getting proper restoration of selectInput() values.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  function(req) {
    fluidPage(
      fileInput("file",
                "Upload",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv"
                )
      ),
      selectInput("select", "Select", choices = NULL),
      selectInput("select2", "Select2", choices = NULL),
      bookmarkButton()
    )
  },

  function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$file, {
      updateSelectInput(session, "select", 
                        choices = c("a", "b", "c"),
                        selected = "a"
      )
    })

    observeEvent(input$select, {
      vars <- c("a", "b", "c")
      vars <- vars[which(!vars %in% c(input$select))]
      updateSelectInput(session, "select2",
                        choices = vars,
                        selected = vars[1])
    })

    onRestored(function(state) {
      updateSelectInput(session, "select", selected = state$input$select)
      updateSelectInput(session, "select2", selected = state$input$select2)
    })
  },
  enableBookmarking = "server"
)
```

Restoration of the app state results in correct updating of `input$select` but `input$select2` gets reverted to "b" even if it was set to "c" upon bookmarking.